# Compactly generated vs. compactly constructed causality violating region?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, topology, time-travel

I am currently trying to grasp the nuance between a compactly generated future Cauchy horizon (as per Hawking's chronological protection conjecture) and a compactly constructed causality violating region (as per Ori's spacetime).

From what I understand, a compactly generated one is just when the past geodesics of the region lead back to a compact region in some achronal spacelike hyperslice. So if we have some big partial Cauchy surface $S$, something of the form $J^-(H^+(S)) \cap S $ being compact. Basically the creation of the chronology violating region stems from finite region of space.

On the other hand, compactly constructed causality violating region seem to be defined by $\overline{D^+(U)}\cap \mathcal{V}(M) \neq \varnothing$, with $U$ some compact subset of $S$ and $\mathcal{V}(M)$ the causality violating region. So there are CTCs in the closure of the Cauchy horizon (so equivalently I suppose, $H^+(U) \cap \mathcal{V}(M) \neq \varnothing$). The definition comes from "[Geometric analysis of Ori-type spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1929)" as the concept doesn't seem to be written down in Ori's papers.

While I can appreciate that their definitions are different, I am having a hard time grasping how a compactly constructed CTC isn't also compactly generated. Ori does go on to [say that](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0503077)

"We emphasize again that although probably not ”compactly generated”, our model does demonstrate the formation of closed causal loops from the initial data on a compact vacuum region $S_0$."

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9907007) also mentions :

"How can this spacetime evade the theorems of Tipler and Hawking? The answer is that
N is not in fact the fountain where the causality violating region originates, but rather a place where the Cauchy horizon terminates. The origin of the causality violation lies outside the region where the weak energy condition is obeyed."

So I am not sure exactly what is going on there and where the subtelty lies between the two.